# can you tell me what's the error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello can you please tell me , what's the error in this program :-

```
set SERVEROUTPUT on;
create or replace procedure pro_industry
(P_SSN IN INDUSTRY.INDUSTRYID%TYPE) IS  V_UnionId 
industry.unionid%TYPE;
V_ABNNUMBER BUSINESS_INDUSTRY.ABNNUMBER%TYPE;
begin select BUSINESS_INDUSTRY.ABNNUMBER,industry.unionid  INTO 
V_ABNNUMBER,V_UnionId from BUSINESS_INDUSTRY B , INDUSTRY  WHERE
BUSINESS_INDUSTRY.INDUSTRYID=p_ssn

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (V_UnionId||'    '|| V_ABNNUMBER);                         
END PRO_INDUSTRY;
```

EXECUTE PRO_INDUSTRY sql developer is showing the following errors :-

> Error(9,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and Error(15,2): PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: this procedure has two statements; comment one and try again, this will tell you where the error is

Comment: A missing semicolon, eh?

Comment: where is the semi colon missing ?

Comment: @Aleksej can you please elaborate? didn't get you..

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pro_industry(P_SSN IN INDUSTRY.INDUSTRYID%TYPE) IS
    V_UnionId                               industry.unionid%TYPE;
    V_ABNNUMBER                             BUSINESS_INDUSTRY.ABNNUMBER%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT BUSINESS_INDUSTRY.ABNNUMBER, industry.unionid
      INTO V_ABNNUMBER, V_UnionId
      FROM BUSINESS_INDUSTRY B, INDUSTRY
     WHERE BUSINESS_INDUSTRY.INDUSTRYID = p_ssn; /* <-- the missing semicolon */

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(V_UnionId || '    ' || V_ABNNUMBER);
END PRO_INDUSTRY;
```

Comment: It still shows errors tho.. it is showing the following errors upon executionError report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRO_INDUSTRY'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: The message is clear: you are passing a "wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRO_INDUSTRY' "... check your procedure call.

Comment: Can you please explain.. i didn't understand this error.. where did i mess up tho?

Comment: What's unclear? The call to PRO_INDUSTRY has wrong parameters. You have to call a procedure with its correct parameters, How do you call this procedure?